# How do I convert a String to a different encoding in Scala?

Tags: scala, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Force a jar to uses(or the jvm runs in) utf-8 instead of the system's default encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159551/how-to-force-a-jar-to-usesor-the-jvm-runs-in-utf-8-instead-of-the-systems-def)

I have a bunch of Strings that I want to read in as UTF-8. Is there a way to force this encoding in Scala, without passing a command-line parameter?

For example, I want to do something like `val utf8EncodedString = new String(myString, "UTF-8")`.

Comment: Are the strings being passed in on the command line or from a file or from a GUI?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159551/how-to-force-a-jar-to-usesor-the-jvm-runs-in-utf-8-instead-of-the-systems-def

Comment: @opyate It is not a duplicate.  This is for Scala.  The other is for Java.

Answer (score 7):

Strings do not have an encoding in Scala/Java. Internally, they are always saved as UTF-16, but that doesn't matter when you use them. Encoding and decoding happens in the IO classes. You should look at the documentation of the [`scala.io.Source`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.Source$) object, which contains factory methods for creating `Source`s, which take the encoding as a parameter.

Comment: Hmm, so I tried using `Source.fromBytes(text.toLowerCase.getBytes(), "UTF-8").mkString` to convert my text into UTF-8, but that didn't work -- I'm probably still misunderstanding how to use `Source`. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? (To give some more context, what I'm trying to do is take Chinese text and be able to split it into individual Chinese characters.)