# How to save Thai word into database table from a CSV file using java?

Tags: java, sql-server, csv, thai

I have developed a java project where I have read a CSV file and inserted the record into a DB table using Java prepared statement. In the CSV file, there are some records where a column called "Name" have Thai name. The database is MSSQL Server. When I get record from CSV file and insert into a table using java prepared statement from eclipse IDE, the Thai name is successfully saved into the database. But when I create the eclipse project as executable JAR file and run the jar from windows command prompt, the value of name column saved as "?????" instead of Thai name.

Please suggest the possible solution as we need to deploy the JAR into production environment.

Comment: Which JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: I am using sqljdbc42.jar

Comment: enforce utf-8 encoding. this thread may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159551/how-to-force-a-jar-to-useor-the-jvm-that-jar-runs-in-utf-8-instead-of-the-syst

Comment: Sounds like you're using a`varchar` not an `nvarchar`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @leccionesonline. I have checked that Thai characters are inserted if we used the command 'start java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar source_file.jar'  instead of 'java -jar source_file.jar'.

Comment: Hi IB1990 if my comment was useful, dont forget to upvote it. that's how this works. thank you